# How to create tables in sql database with Entity framework at runtime and update model at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I know that when I use ado.net, I can create database or table at run-time programmatically like:

```
String str;
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");

str = "CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase ON PRIMARY " +
    "(NAME = MyDatabase_Data, " +
    "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseData.mdf', " +
    "SIZE = 2MB, MAXSIZE = 10MB, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
    "LOG ON (NAME = MyDatabase_Log, " +
    "FILENAME = 'C:\\MyDatabaseLog.ldf', " +
    "SIZE = 1MB, " +
    "MAXSIZE = 5MB, " +
    "FILEGROWTH = 10%)";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
try 
{
    myConn.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("DataBase is Created Successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
finally
{
    if (myConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        myConn.Close();
    }
}
```

But I am using entity framework and I have some work in which I have to create tables at runtime. I have searched a lot about it but no way I got. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406557/nhibernate-fluent-nhibernate-dynamic-column-mapping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entity framework is not for scenarios where you don't have static database schema.

Reasons:

- Entity framework mapping is static - dynamic modification requires, changes of XML files describing the mapping at runtime and using modified files instead.
- Even with changed mapping you still don't have changed or newly created entity classes in your code. EF doesn't support `dynamic` so the only way is either dynamically load assembly with new classes created prior to creating tables or heavy usage of `Reflection.Emit` and let your program "write itself".

If you only need to create a database but tables will be always same you should be fine. You can use that ADO.NET code to create database and tables and pass only modified connection string to the constructor of your context. But the requirement is static database schema = no changes in table's definition.

Comment: Can you give an example on create a database but tables will be always same. And Also how to modify the connection string in app.config / web.config from the values of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework also has similar functions like `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`, you may try `SomeEntities.ExecuteStoreCommand("some sql statements")`.

Considering Entity Framework requires mappings between data models and database, it looks not possible to create/modify tables directly with integrated query language (otherwise the data models need to be modified at run time). Therefore, with no solid references supporting this point of view, I think `SomeEntities.ExecuteStoreCommand()` may be the only way.

Comment: Then how can i use SomeEntities.AddTo..(); method for that table

Comment: That's the problem. Because you don't have static data model mappings, SomeNonExistEntities.AddTo...() is not available when you write the code. The solution I can propose is to use SQL statements completely...

Comment: I admit it's not elegant at all. Considering .NET 4 has _dynamic_ objects, there may be solutions related with _dynamic_ in the future release of Entity Framework I guess? Or there may be more elegant solutions on current version? Let's wait for others' answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this thread:
[NHibernate / Fluent NHibernate Dynamic Column Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406557/nhibernate-fluent-nhibernate-dynamic-column-mapping%5B%5D)

> better off using a key-value store such as Redis or a schema-less database like CouchDB instead of SQL